# convert xsd to WSDL?

Tags: xml, soap, wsdl, schema

I am very confused how i am suppose to send data to a server. I have a .xsd file and i only realized 1 hour ago (and did research) that the schema is actually describing the XML data i am suppose to send. But i have NO idea how i am suppose to generate a XML from it. I dont think i am suppose to go through it by hand? I never used a WSDL file but someone said its nice because i link to it and i can call functions and it figures out lots of data for me.

Comment: Not sure where to start with this one.

Comment: What language/web services stack are you using?

Comment: Please don't post the same question multiple times, with different wording, hoping for a different result.

Comment: i'm using perl. I have no idea what the server is using.

Answer (score 1):

for creating xml from xsd try altova xml spy

[link text](http://www.altova.com/xmlspy.html)

Answer (score 0):

I may be a novice in this field, but if you want to send data to the server I beleive you need to first generate a stub from the WSDL file URL. Then once you have the stub generated you can worry about trying to send data to the server.

Obviously it would help if we knew how you intended to use it/ what language your were using.